# suds 3 `__inject` raises AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'promotePrefixes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, suds

This code is typically working with python 2.7 while raise this error on python 3.7
`billresponse = self.client.service.process(__inject={'msg': body})`

`body` is `str` of xml and it was running on production for more than 2 years while stopped once we upgraded to python 3.7 and installed suds-py3

#### Exception

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'promotePrefixes'
File "./path/to/file.py", line 119, in soap_connect
   billresponse = self.client.service.process(__inject={'msg': body})
 File "/var/www/html/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 559, in __call__
   return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
 File "/var/www/html/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 785, in invoke
   return self.send(msg)
 File "/var/www/html/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 658, in send
   result = self.succeeded(binding, reply.message)
 File "/var/www/html/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 696, in succeeded
   reply, result = binding.get_reply(self.method, reply)
 File "/var/www/html/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 150, in get_reply
   soapenv.promotePrefixes()
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be for a lot of reasons.
Among them, if suds can't parse the response (because it's not receiving the expected xml), it'll raise this error.
To be sure of what suds are receiving, enable suds logs:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```